# Sliding div with jquery in a loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code below works a bit doggy so I need your expertises to solve these two issues. I know many examples out there but I wanted to learn a bit and also have a cleaner code.

1. When sliding, DIV items don't appear side by side. One under another which is wrong.
2. Can I enhance the jQuery code to make it loop or more dynamic so it looks more professional. If I had 100 DIVs then it would be impossible to handle.
3. It should never stop.

Thanks

```
<html>
    <style>
    *           { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    #cover      { width: 100%; height: 300px; background: #CCCCCC; }
    #cover div  { width: 100%; height: 200px; background: #FFFFFF; }
    .content    { text-align: center; }
    </style>
    <head>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                $('#slider_2').hide().delay(5000);
                $('#slider_3').hide().delay(10000);
                $('#slider_1').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
                $('#slider_1').delay(4000).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
                $('#slider_2').show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
                $('#slider_2').delay(4000).hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
                $('#slider_3').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
                $('#slider_3').delay(4000).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="cover">
            <div id="slider_1"><p class="content">SLIDER ONE</p></div>
            <div id="slider_2"><p class="content">SLIDER TWO</p></div>
            <div id="slider_3"><p class="content">SLIDER THREE</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

These animations need to be chained properly. Everything for one element needs to be appear in one statement:

```
$('#slider_1').show(...).delay(4000).hide(...);
```

Otherwise jQuery will likely override the first animation chain (show) with the second chain (delay-hide) in the second statement.

Comment: Ok I chained them now. What about solutions for my 3 questions?