# sliding divs one immediately after another, within an indefinite loop

Tags: jquery

Slowly getting there.

I want to slide divs in from let to right (below), one immediately after another, within an indefinite loop.

`$('#slider_1').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000).delay(4000).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);`

I dynamically get my div IDs and store them in an array like this:

```
var divs    = [];
var i       = 0;

$('#cover div').each(function()
{
    divs.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Now I want to loop through **divs** array and accomplish sliding divs, one immediately after another, within an indefinite loop.

```
    <div id="cover">
        <div id="slider_1"><p class="content">SLIDER ONE</p></div>
        <div id="slider_2"><p class="content">SLIDER TWO</p></div>
        <div id="slider_3"><p class="content">SLIDER THREE</p></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var i = 1;

var go = setInterval(function(){
            $('#slider_'+i).show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 100).delay(400).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 100);
            i++;
            if (i == 4) { i = 1}
         }, 600)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/32Vaq/)

or:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/32Vaq/1)

Comment: If you delete mine and paste your jquery code into [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775855/sliding-div-with-jquery-in-a-loop), you'll see what is wrong but I don't know how what to do. All the divs shows up.